# Getting "Wait until the previous call completes" error while writing data to excel using office.js from Task pane application

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

**Actual Issue:**

After getting the latest updates from windows we are getting “Wait until the previous call completes” error for Office.js ( api method:  Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync).

Most of the users who are using this latest update are facing this issue.( for oder version it is working perfectly)

For the time being we removed windows update from USER machines and uninstalling and reinstalling the MS office.

**Just for info below are our observations:**
We are seeing this when the name ranges to write are huge. This is happening only after the latest update. Before see, same code with the same name ranges number used to work fine.

Modified files are not reflecting on Task pane app for JS file ( but able to see html changes, not sure this a new update issue) even after doing below steps
-   Build project to generate JS files (from Type script).
-   Directly modified JS files.
-   Deleted IE browser cache.
-   Cleaned solution and rebuild again
-   Deleted temp files
-   System restarted.

Not able to attach debugger script process to visual studio (it is working fine with other system).

**Here is the version information where we are facing this issue:**

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if you required further information.

**Updated 1 explanation** 
`

```
Office.select('bindings#' + namedRange, function (callback: any) {

                if (callback.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(
                        namedRange, //The name of the named item. Required.
                        bindingType, // Specifies the type of the binding object to create. Required.
                        {
                            id: namedRange, // Specifies the unique name to be used to identify the binding object. Optional. If no id argument is passed, an id will be autogenerated.
                            //asyncContext: data, // A user-defined item of any type that is returned in the AsyncResult object without being altered. Optional.
                            coercionType: bindingType
                        },
                        // A function that is invoked when the callback returns, whose only parameter is of type AsyncResult. 
                        (result: any) => {
                            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                                var id = result.value.id;

                                Office.select(
                                    "bindings#" + id,
                                    function onError() {
                                        defQ.reject('  Error: Binding not found');
                                    }
                                ).getDataAsync(
                                    {
                                    },
                                    (asyncResult: any) => {
                                        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                                            tracer.Trace("Completed read operation In ReadExcelQPromise method " + namedRange + " time elapsed -" + (Date.now() - startTime));
                                            defQ.resolve(asyncResult.value);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            tracer.Trace("In ReadExcelQPromiseFail1 method " + namedRange + Date() + " ", asyncResult);
                                            defQ.reject('  Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    );
                            }
                            else {
                                tracer.Trace("In ReadExcelQPromiseFail2 method " + namedRange + " " + Date(), result);
                                defQ.reject('  Error: ' + result.error.message);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }).getDataAsync(
                {
                },
                (asyncResult: any) => {
                    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        tracer.Trace("Completed read operation In ReadExcelQPromise method " + namedRange + " time elapsed -" + (Date.now() - startTime));
                        defQ.resolve(asyncResult.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        tracer.Trace("In ReadExcelQPromiseFail3 method " + namedRange + " " + Date(), asyncResult);
                        defQ.reject('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                }
                );
```

Exact Message is : **In WriteExcelQPromiseFail3 method FRWK_Base_GroupLK_MXTue Apr 23 2019 23:55:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Error : **Wait until the previous call completes**

Comment: This is an issue that is best raised on the GitHub repo: [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues)

Comment: Thank you for reporting. While we examine, could you see if the [newer/alternate API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.bindingcollection?view=office-js#addfromnameditem-name--bindingtype--id-) helps with the situation? Note that this requires Office version that supports at least 1.3. The API spec link explains the exact versions involved. It will not work for Office 2013 clients....

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of creating the binding? Is it to get events? In most cases, I don't see a need for binding creation anymore given we can create events and track ranges based on named-items.

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: No Ram, your suggestion is working for us.
I think this has to fix from the Officejs team.